# Swap on video ram in a VM

Tags: linux, vmware, swap, ram

I have a very small VM running in a cloud with only 512 MB ram. I read, it is possible to use the video card as swap as descriped [here](http://en.gentoo-wiki.com/wiki/Using_Graphics_Card_Memory_as_Swap):

> Graphics cards contain a lot of very fast RAM, typically between 64 and 512 MB. With Linux, it's possible to use it as swap space, or even as RAM disk.

Is it possible to use the virtual video card inside a VM also? So I could use more ram than I actually have to pay for?

`lspci -v` output for the virtual video card:

```
00:0f.0 VGA compatible controller: VMware SVGA II Adapter (prog-if 00 [VGA controller])
    Subsystem: VMware SVGA II Adapter
    Control: I/O+ Mem+ BusMaster+ SpecCycle- MemWINV- VGASnoop- ParErr- Stepping- SERR- FastB2B- DisINTx-
    Status: Cap+ 66MHz- UDF- FastB2B+ ParErr- DEVSEL=medium >TAbort- <TAbort- <MAbort- >SERR- <PERR- INTx-
    Latency: 64, Cache Line Size: 32 bytes
    Interrupt: pin A routed to IRQ 16
    Region 0: I/O ports at 1070 [size=16]
    Region 1: Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]
    Region 2: Memory at fe000000 (32-bit, non-prefetchable) [size=8M]
    [virtual] Expansion ROM at 20000000 [disabled] [size=32K]
    Capabilities: [40] Vendor Specific Information: Len=00 <?>
    Kernel driver in use: vmwgfx
```

Comment: Why would you want to do that?

Comment: To get more ram available

Comment: RAM is cheap. Why not just buy some more... ah, I see, you believe you can get more out of your hosted VM. I don't think that there's plenty of VRAM inside a VM available... look for yourself with `lspci -vvv` as described in the articles you're referring to, you'll probably be disappointed.

Comment: This is what I get on `lspci -vvv` https://gist.github.com/rubo77/ce535853d0e2e43a87b8 But I cannot read any ram information

Comment: It says 64mb right there. Are you really running gentoo?

Comment: no. its Debian on a VM. how do you read that it has 64M? And why do you think it's gentoo?

Comment: `Region 1: Memory at ec000000 (32-bit, prefetchable) [size=64M]` is how.  And you've linked to Gentoo Wiki, but that HOWTO should work anywhere.  It's moved to http://gentoo-en.vfose.ru/wiki/Using_Graphics_Card_Memory_as_Swap apparently.

Comment: This question literally blew me away. OMG FFS. OP wants to use GPU (Video) RAM as swap drive / RAM drive. Have you thought about that video RAM being virtual, i.e. fake driver presenting it to your VM from your hypervisor? So it's kinda not there like it is on a real GPU in your Desktop PC. And frankly, the idea is just... simply unbelievable. Video RAM is much more expensive than system RAM, no one would want to do that, even if it was possible at first place.